# How do I create a list from a set of variables with serialised naming in python

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, variables

I have a set of variables which are named as such:
Var_1
Var_2
Var_3
Var_4
Var_5
.
.
Var_95

Each of them contain a dictionary. For example:

```
Var_1 = {
  'Name' = 'Apple',
  'Price' = 1.50
}
```

I would to create a list without having to manually type all of them into the list by changing the number. I'm kind of lost on how I can do a loop on a variable naming without making them into strings.

```
list = []
for i in range(1,95): 
  list = list.append["Var_"+i]
```

Comment: It's better to store in dict instead of list which is convenient to access.

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension and get all variable values.

```
[globals()[i] for i in globals() if i.lower().startswith("var")]
```